# Чтение из файла в разные переменные

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

У меня есть файл, например

```
01#Aq
00#b
111#cw
```

Мне нужно построчно считать содержимое в две переменных:  `01 00 111` в string s1, и `Aq b cw` в string s2 для дальнейшей работы
Как это лучше сделать? Начиталась про getline, но к чему-то простому и рабочему не пришла
Спасибо

Comment: Используйте библиотеки для работы с `csv`

Comment: getline так себе способ. Эффективнее считать данные по максимуму за раз, а уже потом разбить их на нужные блоки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, поток под капотом это и так делает,...

Comment: @Fat-Zer не совсем понял о чем вы

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, стандартные потоки и так буферизируют ввод, если использовать их, то ни какой выгоды от собственной буферизации не возникает... А использование банального `getline()` или аналогов для текстовых файлов — абсолютно нормальная практика... Особенно, когда они сформированы построчно, как большинство конфигов...

Comment: может они и кешируют, но ручное кеширование иногда дает существенный прирост.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getline так getline

```
std::ifstream input("file.txt");
std::string s1, s2;
while (std::getline(input, s1, '#') && std::getline(input, s2) ) {
    std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << " s2: " << s2 << '\n';
}
```